# iPhone: In a custom view, how to draw something on top of everything else in the view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

So I made a UIView subclass let's called it 'MyView' that simply draws a line inside the DrawRect method.

I then drag a UIImageView in interface builder and put it inside MyView. But now when I run the program it's obscuring the line that I'm drawing. I'm wondering, is there a way for me to draw the line on top of the image that I have dragged into my View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to reorganise the view hierarchy. CoreGraphics uses a painters model so views behind will always be drawn over by views infront. To solve this you could use a container view that holds your image view and has a transparent view (line drawing view) that sits over the image view.

Another option is to draw the image using core graphics calls in your drawRect method and then draw the line over it.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have whatever adds `MyView` to add your `UIImageView` on top of `MyView`. It's not ideal (you probably have good reasons for keeping `MyView` and the `UIImageView` in a single class) but definitely solves your problem (I recently did this, only, I added it to the `keyWindow` =)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a CAShapeLayer that has a path representing the line, and insert that layer ahead of the built-in view layer.  Then it should draw on top.